# uitableview table jumps up when image loads with dynamic row height

Tags: ios, uitableview, sdwebimage

I want to implement a tableview with dynamic row height. Heights are based on image data returned from server.

Based on the set row height, the rows are drawn for image that has to be loaded.

But after the image is loaded and gets assigned to the imageview of table, UITableview scrolls to a different position automatically.

Is it because the row gets drawn again? Or

the offset of the table gets disturbed?

Image is scaled by using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale)

I even tried changing the height constraint of imageView programatically every time a cell is configured.I have seen many examples of autolayout working with dynamic heights, but nothing seem to work.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // constant to control height of other views
    return getCellHeight(indexPath.row) + someConstant
}

func getCellHeight(index: Int) -> CGFloat {
// Returns the height of image object based on some cropping and scaling
    return imageHeight
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CELL_IDENTIFIER, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostCell
    ...
    cell.configureForPost(postObject, index: indexPath.row)
    cell.postImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageUrl)
            , placeholderImage: placeholder
            , completed:{(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, imageURL: NSURL!) -> Void in
                if (image != nil) {
                   // do some scaling and assign image to imageView
                }
    })}
    return cell
}
```